# How to render http image in react native?

Tags: react-native

The API is returning HTTP images, in ios they render, but in android not. What to do? 
I already put the authorization in info.plist. And on android how to do?

Comment: Did you use uri tag in Image for react native

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use FastImage dependencies to keep things equivalent across ios and android.

https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image